# opencv - 3D rigid/affine transformation

Tags: opencv, 3d, coordinate-transformation

this is an duplicate question of [opencv: Rigid Transformation between two 3D point clouds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206870/opencv-rigid-transformation-between-two-3d-point-clouds). However, there is no answer accepted and I don't understand the only answer there.

The only answer says scaling and shearing can have different meaning in higher dimension, and gives an example that 2D scaling is 3D translation.

I think a 3D affine transformation should include scaling/shearing in 3 dimensions (i.e. x,y,z axis). A 3D rigid transformation should only have translation and rotation in 3 dimensions.

I am confused that why the answer in the post saying "That's the reason why you don't have an option to set a rigid affine transformation in 3D, because you actually already are performing one"

I should have commented on the original post but I can't due to the reputation requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite what the (now deleted) answer linked in the question (as well as my previous deluded speculation... I blame a bad plate of Arcturian MegaDonkey) might have suggested, `estimateAffine3d` does exactly what it says: estimates affine transformations, including scaling, shearing, translations and rotations, in 3d. The OP has confirmed this (in comments) and I've run several tests in which the transformations were successfully recovered.

There is no reason to believe that `estimateAffine3d` does not work as intended.

Comment: OK, can I put it this way: the estimateAffine3D function in OpenCV only estimates 3D translation and rotation while shearing and scaling appear in 2D is achieved by the 3D translation and rotation. Therefore, the function doesn't estimate the true 3D affine transformation which includes 3D shearing and scaling.

Comment: @linzhang.robot Yes, `estimateAffine3D` only estimates rigid-body transformations. If there exists a true 3D shearing or scaling where the 3D object changes shape, `estimateAffine3D` will try to interpret that as a rigid-body transformation.

Comment: If I have two set of 3D points whose transformation between them includes true 3D scaling or shearing (say points from two cubes have different size). The transformation is estimated by the function `estimateAffine3D`. In this case, a rigid-body transformation won't be able to describe the relation between the two set of points (right?). Can I still use the transformation estimated by the function to align one with the other (i.e. transform one set of point to another)?

Comment: I tested the transformation estimated by `estimateAffine3D` and by another function [estimateRigid3D](http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=671) on a model with markers. The transformations were estimated via the markers. Then the transformations are then applied on the model and the results show that the model's shape is changed (i.e. not rigid) by the transformation estimated by `estimateAffine3D`. Therefore, I think `estimateAffine3D` can estimate a affine transformation includes true 3D scaling/shearing.

Comment: Also, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16354193/two-3d-point-cloud-transformation-matrix) suspects that `estimateAffine3D` assumes the two input point clouds correspond to the same physical points. However, in my case, two point clouds are not exactly same.

Comment: @linzhang.robot I've been looking at the code to try to see what it would do with points that undergo non-rigid transformations (although I'm unclear what "points from two cubes have different size" means) and so far it looks like the points are simply ignored if the error is too great. Have you tried looking at the `inliers` array that is passed back to see if all of your points are included?

Comment: For the cubes confusion, I simply mean two set of points that have only scaling relation between them (e.g. 8 vertices of 2 cubes of different size). Sorry for the bad example. I haven't looked into the `inliers` array. I wrote my own function for estimating the rigid transformation based on [here](http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=671). It is correct (shape not change) when I applied the estimated transformation on my point cloud. I am travelling to a country with limited internet access so I may not be able to reply you promptly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why is this answer accepted by the owner when it is obvious from comments that he knows that it is incorrect (cv::estimateAffine3D estimates full affine transformation and not only rigid-body transformation as it is stated in the answer)?

Comment: @sluki I have no idea; I only vaguely remember writing this answer and would have to investigate again to reconstruct what I was thinking. Perhaps you could write an answer of your own?

Comment: @beaker why would I? The correct answer is already written in the above comments by the author.

Comment: @linzhang.robot Any thoughts?

Comment: @sluki Okay, I've pinged the OP. Not a thing I can do about deleting the answer until they unaccept.

Comment: @sluki I accepted the answer as it helped me think more about the question. Maybe I should put an update in my post and refer future reader to the comment of this post? Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: @linzhang.robot Comments are never the best place to put information. Comments are not permanent and can be deleted by the system at any time. I've verified non-rigid-body transformations are estimated correctly, but I have no clue why OpenCV doesn't include a method to estimate 3D rigid-body transformations (which I think was the original question?). I can either change my answer to say that, or you can unaccept my answer and I can delete it, and you or sluki or whoever else can post a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to update the answer to this question as its the first to show up on google and opencv has changes since.

As of opencv **4.5.3** there is a new overload of [EstimateAffine3D](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.3/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#gac12d1f05b3bb951288e7250713ce98f0) which has the parameter "force_rotation".

Using this overload with force_rotation=true, you will recieve the rigid transformation between 2 sets of 3d points.

I have validated that the results are identical between this and the alternative suggested by OP.